# What is a replacement for meta runners in TeamCity Kotlin DSL?

Tags: kotlin, teamcity, dsl

Apparently there's no support for metarunners generation in TeamCity Kotlin DSL. The files remain in plain XML.

How do I replace it using available DSL features? Say I'd like to do this:

```
steps {
  step {
    type = "mymetarunner" // compound meta-runner step
  }
}
```

How do I define `mymetarunner` using Kotlin?

Comment: Some clarification on why would you need meta-runners defined in Kotlin DSL might help.
Meta-runners are just reusable sets of steps and in Kotlin DSL the natural approach to that is just to extract a method defining the steps.

Comment: @Yaegor, that's what I tried to do, but with meta runners you have a) common set of params for all steps b) logically grouped set of steps that looks like a single one from the outside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment (TeamCity 2017.2), there is no way to define metarunners using Kotlin DSL.

**Update**
If having a real metarunner is not required, the solution is a small exercise in [Kotlin DSL](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html)

Define a container class for settings you need for "metarunner"

```
class MyConfigClass {
  var name = "Default Name"
  var goals = "build"
  var tasks = "build test"
  var someUnusedProperty = 0
}
```

Define an [*extension function*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) for `steps` block

```
fun BuildSteps.myMetaRunner(config: MyConfigClass.() -> Unit) {
  val actualConfig = MyConfigClass() // new config instance
  actualConfig.config()  // apply closure to fill the config
  // use the config to create actual steps
  maven {
      name = actualConfig.name
      goals = actualConfig.goals
  }

  ant {
      name = actualConfig.tasks
  }
}
```

Use the extension function wherever you need

```
object A_Build : BuildType({
  uuid = ... 

  steps {
    myMetaRunner {
      name = "This name will be used by maven step"
      goals = "build whatever_goal"
      tasks = "more ant tasks"
    }
  }
})
```

Bingo!

Comment: Maybe the correct question should be "how do you replace the concept of meta runners with what dsl offers?" Any standard way or example would do

Comment: @AndreyErmakov if you are fine with dsl-only solution (without real meta-runner visible in the TC web UI), I can come back with a solution

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. Also struggling with defining parameters that are real build / project parameters, not just Kotlin function parameters, and used in all steps of such metarunner replacement.

Comment: @AndreyErmakov see my updates above. Hope this helps