# How to import xml of meta runner in Teamcity using kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, teamcity, dsl, cicd

we are using TeamCity 2022.04.4 and have the Kotlin DSL feature very new.

I try to migrate our data towards the Kotlin DSL using a new project and run into the problems with the meta runners.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346645/what-is-a-replacement-for-meta-runners-in-teamcity-kotlin-dsl), that there is no meta runner concept in Kotlin DSL and that I can use extension functions instead.

From an export of our current setup I got some xml files that include the meta runner setup. But when I add them under .Self/metarunners to my new test setup, I cannot see them in the UI.

I would go the way with the extension functions eventually, but this is quite a lot to do and I was hoping to use the xml files from the meta runners in the meantime.

Any idea how I can import the xml files into my Kotlin DSL structure?

Comment: Hey @Ruth I'm in the same boat. You found any workaround for this?